# Perl threads vs. object destructors

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop

Running this perl program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

my $foo = Foo->new();

my $t = threads->create( sub { print "in thread\n" } );

$t->join();

package Foo;

sub new
{
print "Foo->new\n";
return bless {}, 'Foo';
}

sub DESTROY
{
print "Foo->DESTROY\n";
}

1;
```

Produces this output:

```
Foo->new
in thread
Foo->DESTROY
Foo->DESTROY
```

I think this is happening because perl is making a copy of $foo in the new thread and then calling the destructor when the new thread exits and when the main thread exits. This seems like bad behavior to me. It is giving me headaches in my much more complicated, actual program. Is there some way to get perl to not do this?

Comment: Looks like it's by design: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/perl/porters/269726?do=post_view_threaded#269726

Comment: why do you need to use threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to put this in your Foo package:

```
sub CLONE_SKIP { 1 }
```

(assuming you aren't using an ancient perl).

But when you start trying to fight that perl is copying all your code and data at the time you create a new thread, you are entering territory where you might be better off without threads.  You'd have to say what you are using threads for to get good advice on that point.

Comment: Awesome! Your answer is just what I need. I would up-vote it if I had enough points.

Comment: you should be able to accept it, even if you can't upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not construct the object before starting the thread. If the object is really needed in both the threads, consider sharing it - carefully read the documentation of [threads::shared](http://p3rl.org/threads%3a%3ashared) though.

Comment: In my actual program, $foo is not needed by the child thread at all but it must be created and used before and after the child thread is created.